# Law of Large Numbers Detail

Tags: probability-theory

If $X_1,X_2,X_3,\ldots$ are random variables with finite expected values, we say they satisfy the Weak Law of Large Numbers if
$$\frac{X_1+\ldots+X_N}{N}-E\Big(\frac{X_1+\ldots+X_N}{N}\Big)\stackrel{P}\rightarrow 0.$$

We also know that $$\lim_{N\to\infty}E\Big(\frac{X_1+\ldots+X_N}{N}\Big)=\mu$$
for some $\mu\in\mathbb{R}$.

In this case I want to know if is true that
$$\frac{X_1+\ldots+X_N}{N}\stackrel{P}\rightarrow \mu$$

And if it is, how to prove? If it is not, what is the best conclusion I could get from this information?

One last question, if the $X_i$ are iid, it means that $EX_i = \lim_{N\to\infty}E\Big(\frac{X_1+\ldots+X_N}{N}\Big)=\mu$, for all $i\in\mathbb{N}$?

Thanks!

Comment: if the $X_i$ are iid, they have same expectations because same distributions.

Comment: you are right, but if I take out this hypothesis, the conclusion would still hold using that limit for the expectations?

Comment: @mookid I just edited the question, thanks for the observation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of independant variables $X_i$ with expectation $EX_i = m_i$, then let us define
$$
M_t = \frac 1t(X_1+\cdots+X_t - m_1-\cdots-m_t)
$$
This is a martingale.

Let us assume that $(E|X_t|)$ is Cesàro summable.
Now try to use [Doob's martingale convergence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doob%27s_martingale_convergence_theorems):
$$
\sup_t E[M_t^-] \le \sup_t E|M_t| 
\le \sup_t\frac 1t(E|X_1|+\cdots+E|X_t| + |m_1|+\cdots+|m_t|)
\\\le \sup_t\frac 2t(E|X_1|+\cdots+E|X_t|)<\infty
$$
because $m_t\le E|X_t|$, and because of the hypothesis concerning $(E|X_t|)$.

Now because of the theorem: $M_t\to \lim M_t =: M$ in the as and $L^1$ sense.

There is another hypothesis you can see in [Probability with Martingales](http://www.amazon.fr/Probability-Martingales-David-Williams/dp/0521406056), which is $$
W_i\in L^2 \text{ independant}
\\
E W_i = 0
\\
\sum\frac{var W_n}{n^2}<\infty
$$
which implies that $\frac 1t [W_1+\cdots+W_t] \to 0$ as and $L^1$.

Comment: Do $M$ stands for $\lim M_t$ ?

Comment: @Integral yes it does.